# Blocks Folder and blk00000.dat files

Tags: block

In my Bitcoin Folder I found on my old computer,theres also files of  aprox. 130 Mb .dat files. I have now, like I was told dumped the wallet.dat into my new installation of Bitcoin Core, and its running.

Will I need those blk000xx.dat files for any reason ? Are there any cions in them, or information of any value ?

Comment: you don't need the blk000xx.dat files, as it is "only" 130MBytes. The whole blockchain is in the +170 Gigabyte range. When re-downloading the blockchain, you would save maybe 10 minutes (out of several days). These files don't contain any "valuable" data, in terms of bitcoins - they are never in any files. They are "kept" in the blockchain, and with the keys in a file called "wallet.dat", one could move bitcoins from one address to another (hopefully to your own address). So if you have wallet.dat, then there maybe some value.

Answer (score 2):

those block files *are* your copy of the blockchain. you could stop your new bitcoind daemon and move them into the $HOME/.bitcoin/blocks folder and restart bitcoind, and save yourself and the network the necessity to re-download them.